# How to make multiple select results/divs appear in order of most recent selection at top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multiple-select

When I make a multiple selection from the list (see fiddle below), how do I get the results (divs) to show in order of most recent selection at the top? For example, if I multi-selected in the order Nuts, Meats, Vegetables, Fruits, how do I get the results (divs) to appear in the order Fruits, Vegetables, Meats, Nuts? At the moment they appear in the order that they are listed in the box.

https://jsfiddle.net/djj2c84t/

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(mytextbox) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    var options = [];
    $(mydropdown).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({
        value: $(this).val(),
        text: $(this).text()
      });
    });
    $(mydropdown).data('options', options);
    $(mytextbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      var options = $(mydropdown).empty().data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val().replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"));
      var regex = new RegExp(search, "gi");

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if (option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(mydropdown).append(
            $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
          );
        }
      });

    });
  });
};

$(function() {
  $('#mydropdown').filterByText($('#mytextbox'), true);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  function exists(elemt, arr) {
    return (jQuery.inArray(elemt, arr) > -1);
  }

  $('#mydropdown').change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).val();
    $('.mydivs1').each(function() {
      $(this).toggle()[
        (exists($(this).attr('match'), $selected)) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
  });
});
```

I have been trying for four months to search for an answer myself on the web, however, almost all suggestions I have found are either related to 'getting' or 'receiving' the results as opposed to just showing them or to use a certain plugin (Select2, Chosen, etc.) which I do not wish to do.

I have been learning from examples on the web and making my own changes, as my knowledge in Javascript, JQuery and CSS is very limited, so it would be more than appreciated if anyone can provide any help, possibly with any example code and where the code needs to go.

There are a few other things I have not been able to solve but I will refrain from posting too many questions at once and will post them individually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand your problem right.

I made this fiddle for example:

**Edit:**

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/djj2c84t/3/)

it's better to use:

```
$('option').click(function () {});
```

instead of

```
$('#mydropdown').change(function() {});
```

And what i did is to redraw the wanted div inside the "**MainDiv**" that i added

Comment: I am not sure if it is because of my old browser, but in the example you have kindly provided, I am unable to de-select the items at my end. When I ctrl + click on an item I had selected, the div should be removed from the results (or by clicking on the X button - if I figure out how to do this!). Can I also ask why it would not work with my original main div (mydivs1)?

Comment: @TechnoKid try now in the same link

Comment: Almost! Problem now is if I select an item and then type in the box for a new search, I can't remove the item I had selected unless I refresh the page or run the code again. Coincidentally, your code is close to answering something else I want the code to do, which is to keep the results (divs) showing for all items selected even after a new search is performed and a new selection made. For example, if I search for 'F' and select 'Fruits' and then search for 'V' and select 'Vegetables', to have both 'Vegetables' and 'Fruits' divs showing. In the code I posted, 'Vegetables' replaces 'Fruits'.